# Why should the star rating be before the review text box form?

Tags: training

I was wondering how can I rate something before I wrote a review on it. 
what is the best solution to avoid extremely or bad rating on something, Is it to put the rating after writing the review?

What is the best approaches for the star rating?

Comment: Does this question answer your queries: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10046/votes-star-rating-usage-stars-or-smiles

Comment: It have some insights :" the user in a bad mood" But not the exact answer

Comment: I think it is pretty safe to assume that the user already knows what their review is going to be before they start writing it. It's not the act of *reviewing* that determines how a user feels about an item, it's that item itself. They leave a star rating and then comment to describe *why* they have left that rating.

Answer (score 5):

Rating using a set of stars is a quick way for a user to provide feedback, while a big empty text box to type a review in is much more daunting.

If you're interested in actually *getting* ratings, rather than only getting ratings with a detailed explanation of why the rating is the way it is, I think putting the star rating first and the box for a textual review under it is the way to do.

Answer (score 3):

I experimented with this myself recently. With the star rating below the review box people tended to miss the star rating when submitting the review. It's possible some visual design improvements might have mitigated the problem, but simply putting the star rating above the box basically eliminated it.

Comment: Nice experiment, u tested the UI visual design, that people are note it or not. My question is: how about the quality of review and the accuracy of the star rating, is it make any different? the people came and write there review then they rate based on there review... or not.
My problem is that the users came and rate extremely. but there reviews said 2 stars !!

Comment: The tests were done on a prototype, so the reviews weren't real enough to be able to talk about their quality.